# How to loop through to output all possible sentences from keyword search within Shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I created a text search whereby searching for a word, displays the all the sentences having that word in them. However I am getting just first sentence of the output in Shiny when I need to display all sentences based from that word from uploaded text..

```
library(quanteda)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)
library(shinythemes)


war <- readLines("war.txt")


war_corpus <- corpus(war)


sentences <- tokens(war_corpus,what="sentence")


make_sentences <- function(word) {
  grep(word,sentences,value= TRUE)}


sentence_line <- function(word) {
  grep(word,sentences,value= FALSE)}



ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  # Application title
  mainPanel(
    img(src='image.jpg', align = "right"),
    
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             h5(HTML("<strong>Enter a word.Click \"SEARCH\" </strong>")),
             wellPanel(
               textInput("inputString","Enter a word here",value=" "),
               submitButton("Search"),
             )),
      
      column(5,
             h4("Search Results"), 
             wellPanel(                       
               tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
               htmlOutput("mytext")
             )),
      
      column(5, offset = 1.5,
             h6("Uploaded File"),
             wellPanel(
               htmlOutput("showfile"))
      )
    )
    
  ),#Mainpanel
  
)#fluidpage
)#shinyUi



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytext <- renderUI({
    
    res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)[1]
    res1<- sentence_line(input$inputString)[1]
    tagList(
      tags$a(href=paste('#',res1,sep=""),res1),tags$div(res)
    )
    
  })
  output$showfile <- renderText({
    includeHTML("www/final_tokens.html")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

As you can see in the screenshot, for the word 'good' i am getting the first sentence while actually I should be getting all sentences with word 'good' from txt file.(27 sentences for example in word 'good')

[image]

Comment: Why do you put `[1]` in `make_sentences(input$inputString)[1]`? Isn't it the cause?

Comment: getting this error removing [1] : 'Text to be written must be a length-one character vector'

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `[1]`. In the `renderUI`, put:

```
res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)
res1 <- sentence_line(input$inputString)
divs <- mapply(
  function(line, sentence){
    tags$div(tags$a(href = paste0("#",line), line), tags$p(sentence))
  }, res1, res, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
do.call(tagList, divs)
```

Comment: I am not getting the html page output on the right with your solution and also text line number of text --

Comment: `lapply(1:m, function(i){
    res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)[i]
    res1<- sentence_line(input$inputString)[i] `    --- worked for me but outputs almost 50 sentences and when word has only 10 occurences,gives 10 sentences as I wanted but gives N/A after that. anyway I can output  only sentences found and no NA after ?

Comment: @d123 Sorry I forgot something in the `a` tag: this should be `tags$a(href = paste0("#",line), line)`. I don't see why the html page would not appear.